# Insert value based on previously calculated value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table called 'tasks_processes':

```
id| task_id | process_id | start | end  
 1| 2       | 43         | 0     | 250
 2| 2       | 82         | 250   | 500
 3| 2       | 21         | 500   | 750
```

So, 'start' and 'end' columns represent bounds of range and are unique within the task. For new process I need perform INSERT SELECT query like this:

```
INSERT INTO tasks_processes (start,end,task_id,process_id) 
    SELECT 
        COALESCE ((SELECT MAX(end) FROM tasks_processes WHERE task_id=2),0) as new_val , 
        new_val + 250, 
        2, 
        12;
```

In other words I need to insert value based on previously calculated value. But MySQL gives me DatabaseError: no such column: new_val

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to repeat the subquery, like this:

```
INSERT INTO tasks_processes (start,end,task_id,process_id) 
SELECT COALESCE ((SELECT MAX(end) FROM tasks_processes WHERE task_id=2),0), 
       COALESCE ((SELECT MAX(end) FROM tasks_processes WHERE task_id=2),0) + 250, 
       2, 
       12;
```

or you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO tasks_processes (start,end,task_id,process_id) 
SELECT new_val, new_val+250, 2, 12
FROM (SELECT coalesce(MAX(end), 0) as new_val FROM tasks_processes WHERE task_id=2) s;
```

Comment: Great! The second query is neat and looks more safe, I think usage of the first query may cause the break of range because the another process could perform same query during two SELECT(MAX(end),0).

Answer (score 0):

you cant use `new_val` as column ,
try this

```
 INSERT INTO tasks_processes (start,end,task_id,process_id) 
SELECT 
    COALESCE ((SELECT MAX(end) FROM tasks_processes WHERE task_id=2),0) as new_val , 
    COALESCE ((SELECT MAX(end) FROM tasks_processes WHERE task_id=2),0) + 250, 
    2, 
    12;
```